# How to persist data that is entered into a Content Editor Web Part

Tags: content-editor-web-part

I've created a table where users can add/remove rows containing past employment history [Code here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/253768/content-editor-web-part-issue-not-rendering-html)  I'm using a Content Editor Webpart which points to an html file that contains both the code and html.

When I add a row and enter data, that data is lost when I leave the page and return.  I have a second Content Editor Web Part and I've added text to it, and this text is retained when I leave and return to the page.

How can I "save" the rows and data in the fist CEW?

[image]

Comment: Why would you use a CEWP for that when a SharePoint list does it out-of-the-box?

Comment: Because the data comes from SharePoint User Profiles.  When the user clicks edit many of the fields present data in a CEWP.  The problem is it looks awful when you are showing lists such as Education, Work History, etc.

Comment: "when the user clicks edit"... are you saying that you added CEWPs to the user profile page?

Comment: I didn't, our I.T. department did.  Hence, I'm stuck with the hand I've been dealt.

Comment: Scary. You should still store in a SharePoint list, and have the CEWP retrieve from and save to that list.

Comment: Thanks @Christophe.  I suspect they are doing that, but the UI / UX is lacking.  Was hoping improve the look and feel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't persist any dynamic data in CEWP.

Instead, you should base your solution on a SharePoint list and store all data internally in a list. The code in CEWP will show data from that list, as well as store\update\delete items.

Actually, you should think about your solution architecture once again because probably you don't event need CEWP. You can add items directly to the list and use list views instead.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  We are trying to add this information to SharePoint User Profiles.  I don't have access to the backend.  IT presented a table in a CEWP, but we pushed back because the data could not be updated by the end-user.  Thanks.